# `add-load-path!` relative directory in Doom Emacs defaults to `~/.emacs.d/lisp` instead of ~/.doom.d/ where `config.el` sits

Tags: debugging, doom, load-path

As described in the title above, the following code in `config.el`:

```lisp
(add-load-path! "lisp")
```

adds `"home/user/.emacs.d/lisp/lisp"` to `load-path` instead of `"/home/sati/.doom.d/lisp"` where `config.el` lives. This is contrary to the documentation of `add-load-path!` that says:

> Add DIRS to load-path, *relative to the current file.* (emphasis mine)

Funny thing is, when I instrument it with `edebug` and run the code, it adds the correct path to the list.

Wonder what is going on here.